# Icon does not align well with text in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to get the bottom of an icon to line up with some text (to the pixel - the lowest pixel of the first S should be at the same height as the lowest pixel of the foler icon) across browsers, but Chrome is always giving me different results.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LrhB7/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="study-box set-box">
    <div class="set-box-title"> 
        <i class="icon-folder-close-alt">
        </i>
        <div>SHOULD BE LINED UP WITH BOTTOM OF FOLDER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.study-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative; }

.folder-box-title > div, .set-box-title > div {
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 162px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative; }

.set-box-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/W3WW7/1/

```
<div class="study-box set-box">
    <div class="set-box-title"> 
        <i class="icon icon-folder-close-alt">
        </i>
        <div>SHOULD BE LINED UP WITH BOTTOM OF FOLDER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changed:

```
.folder-box-title > div, .set-box-title > div {
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 162px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px; // changed this line
}
```

Added:

```
.icon {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: thanks spencer.  The folder is still not lines up with the text though... it's a couple px higher.  I can't figure out how to line them up to the pixel.